# Error 'The expression refers to multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

Does anyone know why this measure is throwing up an error 'The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

```
MALS Lastweek =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( vw_sana_account[new_mal] ) = 1
        && FILTER ( DateTable, DateTable[LastWeek] = "Yes" )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, your syntax is wrong. This is what you are looking for:

```
MALS Lastweek = Calculate(Count(vw_sana_account[new_mal]), DateTable[LastWeek]="Yes")
```

You dont need `Count() = 1`. It does automatically add 1 in the count function and if you use `Calculate()` your second argument is the filter.

This measure needs a relationship between the `vw_sana_account` and the `DateTable` tables by the way.